# Picking data from xml and adding it to response

Tags: osb, oracle-service-bus

I finished the OSB jumpstart tutorial (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/jumpstart-for-osb-development-page--097357.html) and wanted to extend its functionality.

Currently I get the following response:

```xml
<cus:GetAllCustomersResponse  xmlns:cus="http://www.waai.nl/cdm/customer"> 
    <cus:Customer> 
        <cus:customerId>1</cus:customerId> 
    </cus:Customer> 
    <cus:Customer> 
        <cus:customerId>2</cus:customerId> 
    </cus:Customer> 
</cus:GetAllCustomersResponse>
```

I have an XML file with IDs and name. I am able to extract "1" and "2" from the response. I would like to take names from another XML file with ID 1 and ID 2 and put them in response.

I've tried various things, but all I could get in response was "1 and 2" and the whole XML file.

Answer (score 0):

*Not enought rep to comment.*

Please add examples of your attempts so that problems can be pointed out. What was your last successful step? It's unclear what you meant with

> all I could get in response was "1 and 2" and the whole XML file.

I guess you implemented **GetAllCustomers** operation and are stuck on **GetCustomerById**? 
*Examples of all data would be useful so that there's no need to lookup a download in the referenced article.*

I assume you want to have name field together with id as a response of **GetAllCustomers**. (Or leave only 1 customer with **name** and **id** for **GetCustomerById**?)

---

*Text below is left as FYI and is part of original answer I posted before I read the referenced article closely. The assignment ain't too good of a manual and is partially in Dutch ...*

The basic idea here is to go over customers of **ids** XML in any loop (e.g. `for`) and resolve names from **id to name map** XML. *If response schema allows it **name** can be inserted along with id in **ids**, otherwise you need to modify the schema (or add a new one).*

There are multiple ways to do so. *The best solution is up to you to choose taking into account your data and usecase.*

This can be done via **Insert** action to add data to existing **ids** XML:

1. OSB loop over ids in **ids** and use select name by id from **id to name map** with XPath

Also these are available as options for **Assign** action to create new (merged) XML:

1. XQuery transformation that takes 2 arguments and produces 1 result
2. XSLT transformation that takes 2 arguments and produces 1 result